# Python module to shellquote/unshellquote?

Tags: python, shell, quoting

Is there anything in the Python standard library that will properly parse/unparse strings for using in shell commands? I'm looking for the python analog to perl's `String::ShellQuote::shell_quote`:

```
$ print String::ShellQuote::shell_quote("hello", "stack", "overflow's", "quite", "cool")
hello stack 'overflow'\''s' quite cool
```

And, even more importantly, something which will work in the reverse direction (take a string and decompose it into a list).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pipes.quote` is now `shlex.quote` in python 3.
It is easy enough to use that piece of code.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shlex.py#L281

That version handles zero-length argument correctly.

Answer (score 33):

Looks like

```
try:  # py3
    from shlex import quote
except ImportError:  # py2
    from pipes import quote

quote("hello stack overflow's quite cool")
>>> '"hello stack overflow\'s quite cool"'
```

gets me far enough.

Comment: Sure, `subprocess` is swell for actually starting processes in python, but for code generation, this was just what I needed! +1

Comment: In Python 3, this is `shlex.quote`.

Comment: On windows, `subprocess.list2cmdline` is more accurate. `pipes.quote` always uses single quotes, which is not acceptable in Windows command line environment.

Comment: @asmeurer but pipes isn't deprecated in python3

Comment: [*"Deprecated since version 2.7"*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote) [*"It is finally exposed publicly in Python 3.3 as the quote function in the shlex module."*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote)

Answer (score 10):

To unquote, try  `shlex.split()`

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure that pipes.quote is broken, and should not be used, because it does not handle zero-length arguments correctly:

```
>>> from pipes import quote
>>> args = ['arg1', '', 'arg3']
>>> print 'mycommand %s' % (' '.join(quote(arg) for arg in args))
mycommand arg1  arg3
```

I believe the result should be something like

```
mycommand arg1 '' arg3
```

Comment: fair enough.  but then we need a better solution :-)

Comment: `print 'mycommand %s' % (' '.join(quote(arg) or "''" for arg in args))` ?

Comment: At John's initiative, [this was fixed in Python 2.6.](http://bugs.python.org/issue7476)

Comment: ... but the use of `join` defeats most of the purpose of using `quote` here!

Comment: Why do you say that?

Answer (score 6):

For shell quoting, this works:  I've rigorously tested it on Posix.  [I'm assuming that the `list2cmdline` function supplied by Python works as advertised on Windows]

```
# shell.py
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    from subprocess import list2cmdline

    def quote(arg):
        return list2cmdline([arg])[0]
else:
    import re
    _quote_pos = re.compile('(?=[^-0-9a-zA-Z_./\n])')

    def quote(arg):
        r"""
        >>> quote('\t')
        '\\\t'
        >>> quote('foo bar')
        'foo\\ bar'
        """
        # This is the logic emacs uses
        if arg:
            return _quote_pos.sub('\\\\', arg).replace('\n',"'\n'")
        else:
            return "''"

    def list2cmdline(args):
        return ' '.join([ quote(a) for a in args ])
```

The tests are [here](https://github.com/boostpro/bbot/blob/43cf775186d9f895f69992e800612e1c52a08a49/test/util_shell_tests.py), if anyone cares.

Comment: Counter example: string to be quoted contains `"\xC3\xA9"`, which is an é in UTF-8, and thus not uncommon in filenames. Code above puts backslashes in front of both characters, which  is incorrect. `pipes.quote` will put it in single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library module subprocess has the list2cmdline function which does this, albeit according to [Microsoft rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx) so I am not sure how reliable it works in Unix-like environments for more complicated command lines.

Answer (score 2):

The `quote`function is available for quite some time (Python 2.7?) -- the major drawback is it moved from `pipe` module to `shlex` between 3.2 and 3.3.

You have to be prepared to handle both cases while importing that function:

```
try:
    from shlex import quote
except ImportError:
    from pipes import quote
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to shell quote. The correct way to do a command is to not do shell quoting and instead use [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), and pass a list of unquoted arguments. This is immune to shell expansion.

i.e.

```
subprocess.Popen(['echo', '"', '$foo'], shell=False)
```

If you want to unquote shell quoted data, you can use [shlex.shlex](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/shlex.html?highlight=shlex#shlex.shlex) like this:

```
list(shlex.shlex("hello stack 'overflow'\''s' quite cool"))
```

Comment: What if I need to pass a command (that requires escaping) for ssh to execute once it reaches the other side?

Comment: This is not a helpful answer (well it answers one half my question, so it's half helpful...).  There are are any number of occasions when you need to shell quote -- Mike Boers gives just one great example (in fact, that's the one I'm running into)

Comment: actually even worse, the given example breaks:

(Pdb) list(shlex.shlex("hello stack 'overflow'\''s' quite cool"))
*** Error in argument: '(shlex.shlex("hello stack \'overflow\'\\\'\'s\' quite cool"))'

Comment: From subprocess documentation: If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence. ... This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. - That's just another example where you need quoting.

Comment: This answer is not good, you may be generating a shell script to run later and not executing the command directly.

Comment: My use case for shell quoting is: my Python program is using subprocess.Popen() as suggested, but when it does I'd like it to print something to the console which can be directly cut-and-pasted into a shell, for manual debugging should the command fail.