# Python - passing a string as input to a command

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python module to shellquote/unshellquote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967443/python-module-to-shellquote-unshellquote)

I am trying to pass a string's value into a command as input, in Python for executing a bash command. I currently have somthing like this:

```
cmd = 'echo ' + <StringValue> + ' | command'
output = commands.getOutput(cmd)
```

but it does not work because my string value also contains both " and ', so it parses them wrong. Can anyone please tell me how I can pass this?

Comment: Could you supplement your example with a concrete example of what you are trying to do and the resulting error message? I was able to get the following to at run: `string_input = "bbbb 'aaaa'"; commands.getoutput('echo %s; ls ' % string_input)`

Comment: using `subprocess.call` and passing a stdin parameter is almost certainly better than making a system call to echo followed by a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The `commands` module is currently deprecated since python 2.6 and removed in python 3, you should use the `subprocess` module instead.

The [replacing shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) section in the python documentation should provide the information you need.

Edit: As a follow-up to your comment question, you could use the following code to pass a string to your process:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('cat', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write('abc "def"')
process.communicate()
```

The output this would be abc "def" with the quotes as you're looking for.

Comment: The problem with echo is the following: echo "abc "def""
abc def. As you can see, the " that surround def have disappeared from the output. I would use subprocess, but I don't want to use a file as stdin. How can I use stdin and pass it a string?

Comment: Use a StringIO object instead of a real file.

Answer (score 0):

As for the parsing, you can use triple quotes to have literal " and ' in a string:

```
>>> print """test "a" 'b'"""
test "a" 'b'
```