# replace path in subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am using this:

```
output2 = subprocess.check_output("find /users/experiment_in14 -empty", shell=True)
```

which perfectly working for me but I would like to replace the full path in order to change the path only once at the beginning of the code and not everywhere. 
I am thinking something like this:

```
original = /users/experiment_in14 
output2 = subprocess.check_output("find ,original, -empty", shell=True)
print output2
```

but it doesn't work. which is the right way to replace the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string formatting:

```
original = "/users/experiment_in14"
output2 = subprocess.check_output("find {} -empty".format(original), shell=True)
print output2
```

but you need to be careful with paths that contain shell metacharacters. You'd have to make sure the path doesn't use metacharacters or explicitly [quote the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967443/python-module-to-shellquote-unshellquote):

```
import pipes

original = "/users/experiment_in14"
output2 = subprocess.check_output("find {} -empty".format(pipes.quote(original)), shell=True)
print output2
```

You don't actually need to use `shell=True` here; you can head off any problems by passing in the arguments separately and *not* use the shell:

```
original = "/users/experiment_in14"
output2 = subprocess.check_output(['find', original, '-empty'])
print output2
```

Here `original` is just one more separate argument and won't need quoting.

Comment: thank you very much. it works! i spent so much time to looking for it.