# Python - how to grep using a variable over ssh to remote machine

Tags: python, ssh

I'm  trying to execute remote command over ssh.
all working well from the ssh connection and also with an other simple cmd command like 'ls'.
but, i would like to using ls and grep for a value stored in a variable(ptrn)
but i always failed.
i tried using:

- cmd="ls -ltrd /export/home| grep %s ptrn"
- cmd="ls -ltrd /export/home| grep" + ptrn
- cmd="ls -ltrd /export/home| grep", ptrn

but no luck ):

my code:

```
BuildServer = 1.2.3.4
ptrn = "abc"
cmd="ls -ltrd /export/home| grep ptrn"
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % BuildServer, cmd],shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print (ssh)
```

Can anyone please help me with that?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

If I read you correctly, you want to grep for the contents of the `ptrn` Python variable, so you need to pass that to grep, rather than its name, which doesn't mean anything in that context.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
from pipes import quote

BuildServer = "1.2.3.4" # you pass it as a string to ssh
ptrn = "abc"
cmd="ls -ltrd /export/home| grep " + quote(ptrn) # Don't forget the space after grep.
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % BuildServer, cmd], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print ssh.communicate()[0]
```

As for `quote`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25147580/469220) answer mentions it for quoting shell arguments, so that `grep` will consider it a single argument.

[`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) reads output from the process and waits for it to end.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these:

- cmd="ls -ltrd /export/home| grep %s"%ptrn
- cmd="ls -ltrd /export/home| grep " + ptrn  #notice the space