# Python format json output

Tags: python

I have output from json as below from curl:

```
{'TableViewConfig': {'displayLength': 50, 'Resources': ...}}
```

it needs to be passed in another curl get command with data but in below format:

```
{\"TableViewConfig\":{\"displayLength\":50,\"Resources\":...}}
```

Can you please help in resolving the str replace in python dict?

Tried below, but it didnt work:

```
request = 'url'
response = requests.get(request)
data = json.loads(response)
print(data)
orig = list(map(lambda item: dict((k.replace(''', ''\'), v.replace(''', ''\')) for k, v in item.items()), data))
```

Comment: Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967443/python-module-to-shellquote-unshellquote). HTH

Comment: Can you please elaborate @hd1

Comment: do you need to stringify the data or pass it a json?

Comment: @rose your solution is in that question, it would seem

Comment: @hd1: that is showign error..

Comment: @VivekSingh: stringify

Comment: What is said error, @rose, please add it to your question?